# merging two separate XLS documents based on an ID

Tags: excel

I have two separate XLS documents right now. One has about 400 records, the other has 600.

All 400 records in the first one are required. The other 200 can be thrown away for the purpose of this document, but the 600-record document has a crucial column that I need in the 400-record document.

All records can be matched up via an ID column.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @pnuts, I'm not sure what you mean by a code solution exactly, but I can use SQL.
I am currently trying to write a forumla with Vlookup in Excel but have never used it before.

Comment: My Excel forumla looks like this so far:

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L2,Sheet2!?????,FALSE),"")

Column L is where the row ID is saved on Sheet1 (for whatever reason).

The row ID is saved on B2 in Sheet2
The column I want copied over to Sheet1 is Column F on Sheet2.

Comment: @pnuts Still not working. I get #REF! Error.

Comment: @Pnuts I solved it. Turns out that, since I was only looking up 2 rows from the second spreadsheet, I was supposed to replace the value "5" with "2" (It being the second column from the selected area).**Col_index_num is only counting from the selected columns, not every column in the spreadsheet.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that, since I was only looking up 2 rows from the second spreadsheet, I was supposed to replace the value "5" with "2" (It being the second column from the selected area).

Col_index_num is only counting from the selected columns, not every column in the spreadsheet.